# During insight meditation

Tags: personal-practice

During meditation consciousness of ear nose eye tongue body sensation have disappeared. No sensations for a while  and start emerge of thoughts. When  see the thoughts  clearly there are spaces between them. Suddenly came up a light. Then breath appeared. What is the experience? Is it stream winning?Is the vinnanaya have experience?

Comment: can you add more details on your meditiation practise?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not qualified to say for sure what is happening. But some of what you describe sounds like "the knowledge of arising and passing away", which occurs when your mind clearly perceives the rise and fall of every experience. It may result in blissful, ecstatic feelings, lights, and a powerful religious conviction.

Try to remain aware that these are temporary, conditioned phenomena and not "The Truth", although it may feel like it. It is a very important discovery, but it is not the last discovery, and you may soon also experience painful and fearful feelings, too. Be careful of feelings of extreme joy or extreme fear or despair, and be aware that both extremes will pass.